# Trying to create a conditional dependent dropdown with Apps Script based on cell input

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-statements

I'm new to coding in general, but I'm currently trying to figure out how to use apps script for a spreadsheet project I'm working on. It's supposed to be a little project price tracker for a game, and all the relevant data is already entered and sorted inside the sheet itself.

I'm trying to figure out a dependent dropdown that reads a separate cell with a premade dropdown, then goes to the appropriate sheet + range to create a dependent dropdown based on the value entered.

Essentially, to put it in a sort of flow chart:

breed type -> (if breed type = ancient, specify breed) -> (relevant sheet with genes) -> create dropdown from formula with list of genes

I've seen a few similar examples, but none that do what I need them to.
[This is the general template for the end result; ideally, I'm trying to read the input in the modern/ancient box to determine whether the sheet pulls values from the Modern Gene List or Ancient Gene List.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVUGg.png)
As you can probably tell, I'll be including one version of the function each for the primary, secondary, and tertiary boxes.

I'm genuinely a little lost, so I haven't gotten all that far on the coding aspect.
I started off by combining a couple of similar things I'd found here: (Basic definitions to start the process; dragonSheet/Calculator is the sheet where the above goal template is located, primModern and primAncient are attempting to call the respective gene lists.)

```
function genePrim() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dragonSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calculator");
  var primVal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B15").getValue();
  var destSheet = None
  var primModern = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Gene List - Modern");
  var primAncient = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Gene List - Ancient");

  var breedType = SpreadsheetApp.dragonSheet.getRange("D13").getValue();
  var breed = SpreadsheetApp.dragonSheet.getRange("E13").getValue(); 
}
```

I then started trying to write something to check for the result of the box, but I know that I did it wrong lol. I'm trying to write an if/else where it reads the cell D13 to check for Modern or Ancient, then uses the answer to tell the script to go to a specific sheet from there + create a dropdown in B15 based on what it finds.

This is just the start of the idea, essentially just checking the above variable called "breedType" for the entry and start redirecting to a specific sheet based on the value. For some reason, though, this little incomplete version gave me an "unexpected identifier" error, so I might have written it wrong.

```
 if breedType == "Modern" {
    destSheet = primModern
  } else {
      continue
  }
```

On a correct output, for example, when you enter an answer into the cell, if it read the value "Modern", it would go to the sheet "Gene List - Modern" and select a particular range to create a dropdown from it. (I know how to link a cell for a dependent dropdown, so I essentially just need to figure out how to make the script do it for me.

I will say that the bit of code I DO know is in Python, so a lot of the roadblocks I've been hitting are in assuming that apps script works in the same way. Obviously they have their differences, I just don't know them well yet.

I know this is a little complicated and probably hard to decipher without the data in front of you, so here's the share link with the sheet that you can make a copy from: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j0BOhXIysJhtuVvAmFjlj0jEhGpWaSTPD7ctmwN8fFM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you wish to create a drop down in Google Spreadsheet you must create a Datavalidation Rule and assign it to a range.

Comment: I know how to do dropdowns with data validation (I have a few in this sheet already actually), but I don't know how to make it pull from two separate spreadsheets based on the input from the cell it's linked to. I figured a script would make that easier.

Comment: If you create a datavalidation rule with require in list then all you have to do is to create the string array for the list and assign it to  a cell.[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues)

Comment: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs

Comment: The array formula within a conditional statement ended up doing the job! Thank you for helping me avoid using scripts LOL